# VScode server starts large number of processes

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

When I start VScode on my ssh server and open a workspace with files that take up a lot of storage, I get many processes (at least 10) >10GB in ~/.vscode-server/bin/hash/node. This especially happens when I open a python file. How can I stop this?

Things which resolve the issue:

- changing workspaces
- closing the file

Things which do not resolve the issue:

- turning off git for the workspace
- turning off all extensions
- excluding files from watcherfiles

All of my big files are stored in ~/data/. Here are my user, remote, and workspace watcherfile settings:

```
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/data_BIG/**": true,
    "**/output_BIG/**": true,
    "**/reference_files/**": true,
    "/home/jrich/Desktop/downsample_setup/data_BIG/**": true,
    "/home/jrich/Desktop/downsample_setup/output_BIG/**": true,
    "/home/jrich/Desktop/reference_files/**": true,
    "**/OLD_Desktop/**": true,
    "**/data/**": true,
    "**/output/**": true,
    "/home/jrich/data/**": true,
    "/home/jrich/output/**": true,
    "data": true,
    "**/data/": true,
    "**/data/*": true,
    "**/data/*/**": true
}
```

A typical problematic process reads:

```
PID USER PRI NI VIRT RES SHR S CPU% MEM% TIME+ COMMAND
149158 USER 20 0 11.0G 218M 28612 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.18 /home/USER/.vscode-server/bin/HASH/node --dns-result-order=ipv4first /home/USER/.vscode-server/bin/HASH/out/bootstrap-fork --type=extensionHost --transformERS --useHostProxy=false
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.